# Set default menu link as default menu?

Tags: routes

I have sub menu of Main menu.
I need to set 2nd sub menu as default menu, so when user visit a site 2nd sub menu should open.

Comment: Mark it as expanded...

Comment: I dont want to show children of sub menu.
I just want to show 2nd menu as a default menu

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following modules

- [Context](https://drupal.org/project/context) : It allows you to highlight a menu item if certain condition has been met.
- [Menu position](https://drupal.org/project/menu_position) : This module allows for the creation of rules that will dynamically add the current page into the menu system at the requested spots.

Reference:

- [Menu Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104386/drupal-7-theming-highlight-the-relevant-sub-menu-when-viewing-an-article)

Comment: I already have drupal main menu, but when you visit a site 1st menu open by default. I want 2nd menu should open by default